# what is the reason for intel xdk crosswalk app not installing

Tags: android, intel, crosswalk-runtime

I have intel xdk app downloaded already but the main application still ask me to install version 0.28 through usb. but it always return this error.

**Error Error encountered while installing App Preview Crosswalk 0.28 on your device. Suggestion: Retry.: 600 ADB error.**

returned this code as the reason
**Error 4294967295: Cause: :**

what is the cause?, what must i do?

Comment: does your Windows User Account name have spaces ?

Comment: @Vinay  Yes, I do have spaces in my windows account name, please what are the implications?

Comment: let me know if that works. If not I will try to provide you with another solution.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it. I downloaded  version 2366 and install on a new window account with no space. Then it worked. Next I installed on the account with the spaces in it. I noted that the whole address was used in installation in this version 2366.

Comment: I have accepted your answer first time It

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the Intel XDK currently and it has already been reported.

Let's say your windows user name is "Timothy Nwanwene". The path for the XDK truncates at "C:\Users\Timothy" and doesn't proceed further.

What you can do until then:

1. Create a new user account with no spaces and install/Run intel XDK. It should work.
2. Try installing crosswalk from a different machine and then build/run apps from your machine.